# If I use orderer solo, don't need to make kafka node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

If I use orderer type of solo, don't need to make kafka node?

I trying to set up `virtualbox`.

I plan to set 4VM like this: `orderer`,`peer0(org0)`,`peer1(org1)`, `client`

Should I make VM of kafka??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Kafka and Solo ordering are different.

Be aware that you should not use solo for production. It is for demonstration purpose only.

Here is Fabric FAQ about this: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/Fabric-FAQ.html#id1

You can refer to this for more information.